# How to inetgrate Twilio Video call and Screen share with PHP codeigniter

Tags: twilio

We have a web application written in PHP codeigniter and MySQL. We would like to implement Video call facility along with screenshare. Normally we provide client services so better to have video facility as an advanced feature.

Can you please help how Twilio video call can be implement integrated with our existing codeigniter PHP web application.

Our required workflow -

1. Admin staff will schedule a video meeting with client within our PHP application admin panel
2. Client will join on video call from our PHP application client panel using passcode
3. Both can talk over video call
4. Both can share screens
5. Multiple people can join

Can you please help and how to implement with steps please?

Comment: Hi Sujit, weclome to SO! I am voting to close this question as it's too broad. Please read about how to ask a good question on StackOverflow. Your question has best chance to attract attention and useful answers if it is related to a specific, narrow programming problem. Not asking for full solutions.

Comment: While we don't have a tutorial on CodeIgniter specifically, perhaps this tutorial on [building a video chat application with Symfony](https://www.twilio.com/blog/create-group-video-chat-app-symfony-php-twilio-react) might point you in the right direction.